# google map integration of visualforce page need to display in record

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

i have designed VF page for google map integration and now i wan to display in lead record..
i added it from page layout but its not displaying in record..

Please help..

**VF code:**

```
       <apex:page standardController="lead">
          <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">                 

     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript      

       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
 varmyOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl: false
}
  var map;
  var marker;

vargeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "{!lead.Address__c}, " + "{!lead.Street}, " + "{!lead.City}, " + "      

 {!lead.PostalCode}, " + "{!lead.Country}";

  varinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: "<b>{!lead.Name}</b><br>{!lead.Street}<br>{!lead.City}, {!lead.PostalCode}    

      <br>{!lead.Country}"
      });

  geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK&&results.length) {
if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

    //create map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    //center map
   map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

    //create marker
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: results[0].geometry.location,
   map: map,
    title: "{!lead.Name}"
    });

    //add listeners
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
 google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
   map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });
  }
} else {
   $('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
  $('#map').html("Oops! {!lead.Name}'s billing address could not be found, please make          

  sure the address is correct.");
 resizeIframe();
       }
    });

 functionresizeIframe() {
   var me = window.name;
if (me) {
 variframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
if (iframes&&iframes.length == 1) {
  height = document.body.offsetHeight;
    iframes[0].style.height = height + "px";
  }
    }
  }
   });

   </script>

  <style>
      #map {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:12px;
   line-height:normal !important;
    height:250px;
     background:transparent;
   }
     </style>
       </head>
        <body>
     <  div id="map"></div>
           </body>
 </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code has LOTS of issues and I don't believe it even compiled. You should grab some course in HTML and Javascript...

Visualforce **compilation errors** on things like `<script>` tags that aren't immediately closed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">                 

 </script>
```

And Visualforce also doesn't like stuff like that:

```
<  div id="map"></div>
```

Once I managed to compile it it turned out that your **Javascript had some errors too**. For example you can't put linebreaks like that in a string. If you want linebreaks - use `\n`.

```
var address = "{!lead.Address__c}, " + "{!lead.Street}, " + "{!lead.City}, " + "      

 {!lead.PostalCode}, " + "{!lead.Country}";

content: "<b>{!lead.Name}</b><br>{!lead.Street}<br>{!lead.City}, {!lead.PostalCode}    

      <br>{!lead.Country}"
      });
```

And some variables were initialized incorrectly (you'd get better results by just dropping the `var` keyword completely rather than writing it without spaces...)

```
varmyOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl: false
}

vargeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

etc.

---

Here's a better-ish version. Still has some logical or optimization issues I'd do differently but at least it does show something. (I've removed the reference to your custom `Address__c`)

```
<apex:page standardController="lead">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map;
    var marker;

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = "{!lead.Street}, " + "{!lead.City}, " + "  {!lead.PostalCode}, " + "{!lead.Country}";

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<b>{!lead.Name}</b><br>{!lead.Street}<br>{!lead.City}, {!lead.PostalCode}<br>{!lead.Country}"
    });

    geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK&&results.length) {
            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

                //create map
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

                //center map
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                //create marker
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map,
                    title: "{!lead.Name}"
                });

                //add listeners
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
                    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                });
            }
        } else {
            $('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
            $('#map').html("Oops! {!lead.Name}'s billing address could not be found, please make sure the address is correct.");
            resizeIframe();
        }
    });

    function resizeIframe() {
        var me = window.name;
        if (me) {
            var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
            if (iframes&&iframes.length == 1) {
                height = document.body.offsetHeight;
                iframes[0].style.height = height + "px";
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
<style>
    #map {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:normal !important;
    height:250px;
    background:transparent;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</apex:page>
```